# Angular RXJS Observable Array

Tags: angular, ionic2, rxjs, observable

Im looking to pass an array as an asynchronous observable from my service directly to an ngFor in my template.. Its important that as new members connect and get pushed into this array that they will display right away in the template, and likewise when I get around to writing the disconnect code that they are removed from the array and the template too.

I cant seem to get these values to output in my template here is the function in my service.

```
Observable() {

  let subject = new AsyncSubject();

  let geoQuery = this.geoFire.query({
    center: [this.lat, this.lng],
    radius: 1.609 //kilometers
  });

  geoQuery.on("key_entered", (key, location, distance) => {
    this.nearme.push({ userid: key, userloc: location, userdistance: distance.toFixed(2) });
    subject.next(this.nearme);
    console.log("User near you  " + key + " found at " + location + " (" + distance + " km away)");
  });

  return subject.asObservable();

}
```

and in the component im picking it up here:

```
this.usersNearMe = this.locationTracker.Observable();
```

and then in my template

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="member-group">
      <ion-col class="member-item" tappable  width-33 *ngFor="let m of usersNearMe | async; let i = index">
        {{m?.userid}} 
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Comment: What does the console.log say? What's an `AsyncSubject`? Where is that coming from?

Comment: AsyncSubject is coming from rxjs.. the console says that 1 item gets pushed into the observable but subsequent pushs to the array dont output

Comment: Maybe `AsyncSubject` is the issue? The doc says "AsyncSubject is a variant where only the last value is sent and **only when the execution completes**." In your case, the execution NEVER completes. How about you try with a `BehaviorSubject` instead?

Comment: Im using BehaviorSubject now but its still not passing subsequent pushes to the array out.. I just get one result when there should be 2

Comment: You're saying you see TWO logs in the console but the UI is only refreshed ONCE?

Comment: Yeah basically Im getting this in the console when I output the subscription which shows the first array push then the second user being pushed.. but this is not showing in the template

Comment: What if you instantiate the Subject **outside** of the `Observable()` method?

Comment: Maybe, this is a problem with the mutable array you have. Every time the array is changed you must create a copy of its new representation and do this.subject.next(). Because if no copy is done angular doesn't know if the array has changed. Not sure at all, but you can give it a try.